# What is a Multilayer perceptron with sliding windows and how it is trained and tested

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

What is the definition of the MLP+sliding windows and how it is trained and tested. It is used in time-series prediction/classification right?
For example, I have time series data with 10 features. Length of all time series is 200 time steps. I want to classify them into 2 distinct classes.

```
feature_1 = {............}
feature_2 = {............}
feature_3 = {............}
.
.
.
feature_10 = {............}
```

How do I train a MLP with sliding windows for this case. Lets say I want a sliding windows of 30 time steps. How many nodes would the input be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi Layer perceptron (MLP) is a feedforward neural network with one or more layers between input and output layer.

[image: Multi layer perceptron]

Sliding window means the following schema of work:
1. You consider your line of inputs as slices of some window. For example 30 inputs.
2. You take from 1 to 30 inputs in order to predict 31-st, 32-nd, and how much you need to forecast.
3. Then you take rows from 2 to 31 in order to predict 32-nd, 33-rd, etc.
4. Continue to move in your training.

Comment: Please verify this for me. Lets say that I have one time series, x with 200 time steps. I want the network to do one-step-ahead prediction. Therefore I construct a MLP with say 10 input nodes. Each input node takes a value of one time step from the series. eg: node1: takes x[0], node2:x[1]... node10:x[9]. The try to predict the x[10] at the output node. Then the whole process repeats again but now node1 take x[1], node2:[2].... node10:x[10]. now we predict x[11] at the output. Now in this case I have constructed a MLP with sliding windows=10 am i right?

Comment: What different is then this with time delay neural network (TDNN). How do we apply TDNN?